# Access weapon class damage variable from projectile class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project, I have a Weapon class with a damage variable I'd like to pass to the projectiles when they are instantiated (in the Weapon class). The Projectile class handles enemy hit detection.

I have accessed variables in other classes before using GameObject. It hasn't worked in this case, maybe because the projectiles are instantiated? What is an efficient way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Is the projectile being instantiated from `Weapon` Class? If yes, send damage as part of the constructor.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

when you are instantiating the Projectile then access the script and set the damage variable however you like(passing into the constructor, or implementing the setter and getter for a variable or directly passing the value).

```
GameObject proj = Instantiate(projToSpawn);
proj.GetComponent<ProjectileScript>().damage = yourDamageAmount;
```